# Differences in DATEADD with month and day

Tags: sql, t-sql, dateadd

When I need to truncate the time from a `DATETIME` object, I usually use

```
DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, <myDateField>))
```

and that works fine. Recently I needed to get the first day of the month from a `DATETIME` field, so I used

```
DATEADD(month, 0, DATEDIFF(month, 0, <myDateField>))
```

and I was getting odd results from my queries, so I actually tried this on its own and lo and behold - wrong answer!  I was getting a date in 1903.  Pouring through the documentation, I see it "should" actually be

```
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, <myDateField>), 0)
```

which does work.

So - why does `DATEADD` not have a problem interpreting a (non-zero) integer as a date when using days but does when using months?

Comment: It doesn't - all your statements have errors that end up cancelling themselves when working with dates. Date `0` is 1900-1-1 so `DATEDIFF(day,0,...)` returns the number of days since date `0`. You then add that back to date `0`. 
There are better ways to truncate, eg `CAST(myDateField as DATE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized what is happening.  If `DATEADD` has to cast its third argument from an `int` to a `datetime`, then it assumes that is expressed in days, independent of whatever datepart type is being used as its first argument.  So it converts 1373 (in my case here) to a date and ends up with 10/6/1903 plus zero months, which is what the result is.

Answer (score 0):

This is because...`DATEDIFF(day, 0, <myDateField>)` is basically the integer representation of a datetime and can be converted into a datetime. Your dateadd then adds zero days to it, so it is pointless.

That is why it wont work with a month...`DATEDIFF(month, 0, <myDateField>)` will not be the same value as `cast(<myDateField> as int)` or `DATEDIFF(day, 0, <myDateField>)`

Consider these...

```
select 
    getdate(),
    datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 
    cast(getdate() as int)
```

IMO, it's better to not rely on this. I always use the form `dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, @d), 0)` to remove time. Or `dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, @d), 0)` to move to first of month.

Comment: DATEDIFF isn't a date, it's an actual difference. It just happens that `DATEDIFF(dd,0,...)` is the difference from date `0`, 1900-1-1, so it can be converted to the original date

Comment: I know that, but it is auto converted into a datetime when it's the 3rd parameter of the dateadd function.

Comment: I did read yours. My code is not failing because "DATEDIFF... is the integer representation of a datetime."  It is failing because DATEADD always assumes its last arg is a `datetime` in days (if a type conversion is needed).

Comment: @Conrad but it is failing because of that!!! It's works because the DAY difference IS the int representation while the MONTH difference IS NOT!